# Exporting color coded data from R to Excel in a wide format

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, pivot, openxlsx

```
library(tidyr)

# Create a data frame in long format
long_data <- data.frame(
  digits = rep(1:5, each = 3),
  category = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 5),
  value = c(10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35, 12, 22, 32, 18, 28, 38, 14, 24, 34),
  color_code = c("red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green")
)
```

I have a data_frame in a long format where each value is color_coded. I found it possible to color code this output in Excel using openxlsx library by applying conditional formatting based on color_code. However, I cannot figure out how to do it if I need the final Excel output to be in the wide format but still color-coded.

I wasn't able to find a solution for this. Please help.

Comment: You can pivot your data from long to wide in R and then apply your conditional color formatting in Excel after pivoting. you can apply conditional formatting by setting a rule type using "Format only cells that contain" and for each text value that you have (ie red) format accordingly. can you describe in greater detail at which step your color coding is not working as expected?

Comment: Are you suggesting to write a code for each value and tell Excel what color should it be?That can work for this table, but the actual data is much bigger.

Comment: What is the wide format you are expecting?

Comment: let's say Digits as rows, category as columns, value as value.

Comment: in R, there are several packages that you can use to get the rgb value for the text values (ie red, yellow, blue) that you have. Create an additional column with the rgb values. then in excel, you can probably use those rgb values to format your cells...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* with this code you can specify more specific hexadecimal color values. For example "#00FF00" instead of "green".

```r
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyr)

wide <- long_data |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = digits, names_from = category, values_from = value)

colors <- long_data |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = digits, names_from = category, values_from = color_code)

color_loc <- map(set_names(unique(long_data$color_code)), ~ as.data.frame(which(colors == .x, arr.ind = TRUE)))
color_style <- imap(color_loc, ~ createStyle(fontColour = .y))

wb <- write.xlsx(wide, "output.xlsx")
iwalk(color_loc, ~ addStyle(wb, 1, color_style[[.y]], rows = .x$row + 1, cols = .x$col))                    
saveWorkbook(wb, "output.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

1. `wide` is the wide format data and `colors` is the same structured data but with the cell-level color as values.

```r
> wide
#   digits     A     B     C
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1    10    20    30
# 2      2    15    25    35
# 3      3    12    22    32
# 4      4    18    28    38
# 5      5    14    24    34

> colors
#   digits A     B     C    
#    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1      1 red   red   red  
# 2      2 red   blue  blue 
# 3      3 blue  blue  blue 
# 4      4 green green green
# 5      5 green green green
```

2. For each unique color, we get the row and column index location of all cells for that color. So, this code will work if you change the colors, add colors, and/or remove colors:

```r
> color_loc
# $red
#   row col
# 1   1   2
# 2   2   2
# 3   1   3
# 4   1   4
# 
# $blue
#   row col
# 1   3   2
# 2   2   3
# 3   3   3
# 4   2   4
# 5   3   4
# 
# $green
#   row col
# 1   4   2
# 2   5   2
# 3   4   3
# 4   5   3
# 5   4   4
# 6   5   4
```

3. For each color we create a sheet style `color_style`.
4. Lastly, after creating a workbook object (`wb`), we apply the each style to the specific row and column index (row + 1 to account for the header row in Excel).

**Output**

[image]

Comment: hey quick question, I was trying to figure out how to use the ```col2rgb``` function in R. I tried to create a custom column containing rgb values from the text values by doing ```long_data %>%
                    mutate(col.val = col2rgb(color_code))``` but instead of returning just the rgb values for each text value, I can only get a list of all the rgb values for each value in the color_code column. any ideas how to get just one rgb value at a time?

Comment: @BrendaThompson, `color2rgb` returns a matrix, which is why you are having issues with your code. Try something like `long_data |> mutate(col.val = lapply(color_code, col2rgb))`, but do realize that `col.val` is then a list-column.

Comment: I thought about a similar solution that would output two data tables in wide format onto excel, one with the actual data and another one with colors. Then use conditional format in Excel to color the cells. You solution is obviously superior. Thank you.

Comment: I will test it with my actual data and mark it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @BrendaThompson you could do something like `long_data |> mutate(col.val = lapply(color_code, \(x) data.frame(t(col2rgb(x))))) |> tidyr::unnest(col.val)`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Pivot data as described
wide_data <-
  long_data |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = category,
              values_from = c(value, color_code))

library(openxlsx)

# Prepare the sheet with the data
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
# we only write the values, not the color columns to the sheet
writeData(wb, "sheet1", wide_data[1:4])

# function that creates a style for the supplied color
color_style <- function(x)
  createStyle(fontColour = x)

# function that iterates through column cells and applies font color styles
color_cells <-
  function(colors, col_index, row_index)
    walk2(
      colors,
      row_index,
      \(x, y) addStyle(
        wb,
        "sheet1",
        color_style(x),
        cols = col_index,
        rows = y + 1
      )
    )

# put it all together and apply it to the value columns
walk2(wide_data[5:7],
     LETTERS[2:4],
     \(x, y) color_cells(x, y, seq_along(x)))


# save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "color.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```